# What is the correct way to escape text in JSON responses?

Tags: php, json

I am generating the json from PHP.

Comment: Smallest Question Ever :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The correct way is to use [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/json_encode)

Comment: Right, *you* wouldn't ever want to escape the text, you let the library do it

Comment: For the Googling masses: json_escape() misses many important characters that will choke up a super-strict JSON validator (iPhone JSON libraries in my experience; errors not found by jslint.com or jsonlint.com). Examples are tabs and returns \t \r

Answer (score 2):

The JSON is just a subset of Javascript, so everything you know about escaping strings in Javascript applies to JSON.

And yes, the correct answer is to use one of library functions, there is a quite a few of them around: see [A completely fair and balanced comparison of php json libraries](http://gggeek.altervista.org/sw/article_20061113.html).