# missing ) after argument list

Tags: php, javascript

I'll show the main parts of the code as most of it is irrelevant:

```
    $url = $row['url'];
    echo "<div id='anything'><img id='$url' src='$cover' alt='$title' onclick='myFunction($url)'>";
```

and the javascript function:

```
 function myFunction(something) { 
 alert (something);
 }
```

I recieve the following error in firebug:

```
missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]   
    myFunction(http://anything.com/anything...
-------------------^
```

I am relatively new to javascript but I can tell it is obviously not allowing the ":" from the url. However, I can't change or alter the id, as I need to alert the exact id of the Image.

I have made this work in a different format without the php, so I assume it's there where the problem lies?

Comment: String != random character sequence. You do need those quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
$escapedString = json_encode($url);
echo "<div id='anything'><img id='$url' src='$cover' alt='$title' onclick='myFunction($escapedString)'>";
```

T.J. Crowder is right, and you can check this out for more information:

[What is the correct way to escape text in JSON responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253031/what-is-the-correct-way-to-escape-text-in-json-responses)

Why is my first solution incorrect (even if it seems to work with 1 case)?

Read this: http://kunststube.net/escapism/

```
echo "<div id='anything'><img id='$url' src='$cover' alt='$title' onclick='myFunction(\"$url\")'>";
```

You basically need to print double quotes around the the value passed into the myFunction call:

```
onclick='myFunction(\"$url\")'
```

Comment: And if the URL happens to contain other characters that are special? Backslashes, for instance?

Comment: Oh damn, I don't know why I didn't try that. Thanks that makes sense and it works!!

Comment: The URL can contain anything that can be in a URL, I can't really stop that.

Comment: @user1: Right, so you handle it by properly and thoroughly encoding the URL, rather than just throwing quotes around it and hoping for the best.

Answer (score 4):

The URL needs to be a string, but you're just outputting the string's contents.

You *could* just put quotes around it as suggested elsewhere, but that's at best an incomplete solution.

Fortunately, PHP gives you a better answer: [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) combined (in your case) with [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). This is a function that (amongst other things) will properly wrap a string for you such that you can use it in JavaScript code. So:

```
$escapedUrl = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($url));
```

then

```
...onclick='myFunction($escapedUrl)'...
```

`json_encode` is for encoding text as JSON, but as JSON is a subset of JavaScript literal notation, and `json_encode` quite happily returns a valid, properly-escaped JavaScript string...

You need the `htmlspecialchars` as well because you're then outputting the JavaScript code you're generating into the `onclick` attribute, and the content of all HTML attributes in HTML text (even ones with code in them) must be properly encoded so (for instance) `&` must be `&amp;`, etc.

Comment: @clentfort No, when json_encoding strings, you get a quoted string.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are doing something like this:

```
myFunction(http://anything.com)
```

Function parameter need to be enclosed within quotes or doble quotes in case of string parameters:

```
myFunction("http://anything.com")
```

So your echo should look like:

```
"<div id='anything'><img id='$url' src='$cover' alt='$title' onclick='myFunction(\"$url\")'>"
```

Also you should take into account that `$url` doesn't have to contain valid characters, so you should add some encoding/escaping (think in terms of XSS).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `encodeURI(uri)` function:

```
"<div id='anything'><img id='$url' src='$cover' alt='$title' onclick='myFunction(encodeURI(\'$url\'))'>";
```

Comment: `encodeURI` has nothing whatsoever to do with escaping JavaScript strings.

Comment: I don't know why but the encodeURI made some of the URL's invalid for example http://www.thedoowopjukebox.com/oct08/Flamingos%20-%20Golden%20Teardrops%20%28Rare%20Echo%20Version%29.mp3 went to http://www.thedoowopjukebox.com/oct08/Flamingos%2520-%2520Golden%2520Teardrops%2520%28Rare%2520Echo%2520Version%29.mp3

Comment: @user1: The reason is simple: It's not the tool you use for this job.